# Third Party Time Limiting software mac

Tags: parental-controls, administrator

Is there a time limit software for mac that does exactly what the "Bedtime" feature in Parental Controls does, except separately from the System Administrator framework?

Here's what I want to do: I want my Mac to lock me out during a certain time-frame every day, say 10pm to 6am. And I don't want to be able to bypass this. But I don't want to lose my System Admin privileges (install/uninstall, delete apps, etc). If I set up the Parental Controls I have to give that password to someone else.

Is there a software that will allow me to set a 'curfew' for my mac with a password protection separate from my System Admin?

Answer (score 1):

[Watcher](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9037/watcher) is not free, however, it allows setting of a curfew, and some other features that may help you work more productively.